# Google App Engine Over quota error

Tags: google-app-engine

The recommended way by Google to capture the over quota error when you run out of money on your credit card seems not to capture the error:

error_handlers:
    - error_code: over_quota
      file: over_quota.html

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin



- url: /test.*
  login: admin
  script: groupbuy/tests/gaeunit.py

- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine/appstats/ui.py

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /static
  static_dir: groupbuy/static

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: groupbuy/static/robots.txt
  upload: groupbuy/static/robots.txt

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

It seems the error handler `over_quota.html` is not captured, what could be wrong in the urls or is it ordering?

Comment: can you paste the complete app.yaml file?

Comment: @proppy I have added the whole app.yaml file check it out.